# How is depth perception (e.g. in autonomous driving) addressed without using a Lidar or Radar unit?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, applications

For practical applications, like autonomous driving, depth perception is needed to make useful decisions.

How is this normally addressed without using a LIDAR or RADAR unit (but using a camera)?

Comment: Usually you need two cameras, rt to observe the same point from two different angles, like our eyes do to create a stereo image.

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d53/tutorial_py_depthmap.html

Comment: I don't know about any single camera-based depth perception based thing but there is software used by some game devs  for large buildings that involves a drone or some camera that photographs a location from every angle possible.

Comment: Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks, now how would one separate the ground plane from objects laying on it? The simplest idea is to angle your cameras to now include video right infront of the bottom of the robot but that could miss things.

Comment: I am afraid I don't really know. I haven't worked on that specific stuff in CV.